# Is there a way to remove functions appearing in R summary?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

[image]

I am using this R "jump to" tool for my project, and I've noticed that certain functions keep appearing in the generated summaries. I would like to know if there is a way to prevent these specific functions from being included in the summary output. I've already tried searching for a solution, but I haven't found anything helpful so far.

How can I remove these functions from the summary? Are there any parameters or options I can use in the summarization tool to achieve this customization?

Comment: What packages are you using? How do you form this model? Is this for an Rmd/Qmd document, or is this just showing up in your console or RStudio environment? This looks nothing like a frame, why did you tag [tag:dataframe]?